# Three.js - Trying to use WebGL - Skinned Mesh Avatar

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh, avatar

I have been trying to display an avatar (skinned mesh) on Safari using WebGL (three.js r71). The code is below (I have already set up the camera, lighting, scene and renderer):

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();  
            loader.load( 'models/avatar.json', addModel );

            guiControls = new function() {

                this.mPelvis = 0.0;
                this.mTorso = 0.0;
                this.mChest = 0.0;
                this.mNeck = 0.0;
                this.mHead = 0.0;
                this.mSkull = 0.0;
                this.mEyeRight = 0.0;
                this.mEyeLeft = 0.0;
                this.mCollarLeft = 0.0;
                this.mShoulderLeft = 0.0;
                this.mElbowLeft = 0.0;
                this.mWristLeft = 0.0;
                this.mCollarRight = 0.0;
                this.mShoulderRight = 0.0;
                this.mElbowRight = 0.0;
                this.mWristRight = 0.0;
                this.mHipRight = 0.0;
                this.mKneeRight = 0.0;
                this.mAnkleRight = 0.0;
                this.mFootRight = 0.0;
                this.mToeRight = 0.0;
                this.mHipLeft = 0.0;
                this.mKneeLeft = 0.0;
                this.mAnkleLeft = 0.0;
                this.mFootLeft = 0.0;
                this.mToeLeft = 0.0;

                this.rotationX = 0.001;
                this.rotationY = 0.001;
                this.rotationZ = 0.001;

                this.scaleX = 3;
                this.scaleY = 3;
                this.scaleZ = 3;

                this.scene = function(){
                console.log(scene);

                };
            }




            datGUI = new dat.GUI();

            datGUI.add(guiControls, "scene");

            var cfolder = datGUI.addFolder('Controls');

            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mPelvis',-1.57, 1.57); 
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mTorso',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mChest',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mNeck',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mHead',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mSkull',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mEyeRight',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mEyeLeft',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mCollarLeft',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mShoulderLeft',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mElbowLeft',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mWristLeft',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mCollarRight',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mShoulderRight',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mElbowRight',-1.57, 1.57); 
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mWristRight',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mHipRight',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mKneeRight',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mAnkleRight',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mFootRight',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mToeRight',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mHipLeft',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mKneeLeft',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mAnkleLeft',-1.57, 1.57);    
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mFootLeft',-1.57, 1.57);   
            cfolder.add(guiControls, 'mToeLeft',-1.57, 1.57);    


            var rfolder = datGUI.addFolder('Rotation');

            rfolder.add(guiControls, 'rotationX', -1 ,1);
            rfolder.add(guiControls, 'rotationY', -1 ,1);
            rfolder.add(guiControls, 'rotationZ', -1 ,1);


            var sfolder = datGUI.addFolder('Scale');

            sfolder.add(guiControls, 'scaleX', 0 , 1);
            sfolder.add(guiControls, 'scaleY', 0 , 1);
            sfolder.add(guiControls, 'scaleZ', 0 , 1);

            datGUI.close();

            var helpset;


            function addModel( geometry,  materials ){

                    materials[0].skinning = true;
                    objeto= new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
                    scene.add(objeto);

                    helpset = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(objeto);
            //      scene.add(helpset);

            } 

        }

        // Your render function
        function render() {

            scene.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh){  

                    child.rotation.y += .01;
                    child.scale.x = guiControls.scaleX;
                    child.scale.y = guiControls.scaleY;
                    child.scale.z = guiControls.scaleZ;

                    child.rotation.x = guiControls.rotationX;
                    child.rotation.y = guiControls.rotationY;
                    child.rotation.z = guiControls.rotationZ;

                    child.skeleton.bones[0].rotation.z = guiControls.mPelvis;
                    child.skeleton.bones[1].rotation.z = guiControls.mTorso;
                    child.skeleton.bones[2].rotation.z = guiControls.mChest;
                    child.skeleton.bones[3].rotation.z = guiControls.mNeck;
                    child.skeleton.bones[4].rotation.z = guiControls.mHead;
                    child.skeleton.bones[5].rotation.z = guiControls.mSkull;
                    child.skeleton.bones[6].rotation.z = guiControls.mEyeRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[7].rotation.z = guiControls.mEyeLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[8].rotation.z = guiControls.mCollarLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[9].rotation.z = guiControls.mShoulderLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[10].rotation.z = guiControls.mElbowLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[11].rotation.z = guiControls.mWristLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[12].rotation.z = guiControls.mCollarRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[13].rotation.z = guiControls.mShoulderRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[14].rotation.z = guiControls.mElbowRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[15].rotation.z = guiControls.mWristRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[16].rotation.z = guiControls.mHipRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[17].rotation.z = guiControls.mKneeRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[18].rotation.z = guiControls.mAnkleRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[19].rotation.z = guiControls.mFootRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[20].rotation.z = guiControls.mToeRight;
                    child.skeleton.bones[21].rotation.z = guiControls.mHipLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[22].rotation.z = guiControls.mKneeLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[23].rotation.y = guiControls.mAnkleLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[24].rotation.y = guiControls.mFootLeft;
                    child.skeleton.bones[25].rotation.y = guiControls.mToeLeft;

                }

                else if  (child instanceof THREE.SkeletonHelper){
                    child.update();
                }
            });

        }

        function animate(){


            render();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        }

        init();
        animate();
```

When I delete the materials[0].skinning = true; line I have my avatar displayed on browser, but the bones do not move. Do you I have to enable skinning in order to rotate the bones?

Comment: Use the non-minified version -- three.js, not three.min.js --- for development and debugging. Step through with the debugger.

Comment: Which one should I use Three.js or three.js? I have tried the three.js (r71) and it is giving me similar issue: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'bones[ gbone.parent ].add')".

Comment: When I use the Three.js, there is an error creating the scene. Besides, how can I use the debugger? I tried to click the 'step into' button, but it wasn't working.

Comment: I have just managed to use the debugger and the HTML file is giving me no errors anymore. The problem now is that the avatar is not being displayed. Now I really don't know what the problem might be.

Comment: I have changed the avatar to one that does not assign mesh/bones parenting to null and it worked. But now I am getting a new error: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.initialized')". Do you know how to fix it? I am using three.js (r71), which has already fixed the #5542 bug (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5542).

Comment: If you need help, you need to file a post with sufficient information so the problem can be reproduced. I expect you are able to figure things out yourself, however.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. Yes, I do have to enable skinning in order to rotate the bones.